# Screen or view when referring to content on the screen?

Tags: single-word-requests

Having content on the screen (e.g. a computer screen or the screen of a mobile device), how do I refer to that content? Is it "view" or "screen"? I am looking for an everyday term, not a formal one.

*Update:*
The context is the description of the various screens/views that a user can experience when using a finance app for iPhone (e.g. in/on the add expense-view/screen).

Comment: It depends on the context, and on the content.

Comment: The word choice is (to me, anyway) context dependent, and there is not enough context in the question for a good answer. A general rule of thumb, though, is that when considering to use one word or the other, I would opt for the one that reduces ambiguity. So if I had been using the word "screen" to refer to the physical part of the iPhone upon which content is displayed, and I would use "view" to refer to the content being displayed. Discussing a camera app, and talking about the different views of the subject of the photo, I'd might use "screen" to refer to content.

Comment: I would say that both are in use, but have you considered _page_? That's drawing a vague analogy with a website, and my subjective opinion is that it's a more user-friendly term (whereas _screen_ and _view_ are both technically driven, in my opinion).

Comment: @Morton You have a point. However, I have never seen the use of "page" in this context... But then again, I have a technical background and mostly read technical stuff. Would be nice to get a regular app consumer's opinion...

Answer (score 2):

It's a **window**. Even on apple devices ;)

> window *Computing* A framed area on a display screen for viewing information. - [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/window)

ODO examples:

> The viewer gets the video and audio directly into his Internet browser window.
>
> Other differences relate to the rules for entering a phrase into the search engine phrase window.
>
> You may need to scroll or resize the pop-up image window to get a good view.

Answer (score 1):

The word ***screen*** appears more appropriate for your requirement.

ODO:

> **[screen](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/screen)** 
>   *NOUN*
>
> 2.3 The data or images displayed on a computer screen: pressing the F1 key at any time will display a help **screen**

Answer (score 0):

In the context of RWD, that's called *viewing environment*.

> A site designed with RWD adapts the layout to the **viewing environment** by using fluid, proportion-based grids, flexible images, and CSS3 media queries,an extension of the @media rule,.... ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design))

Also, *viewing experience* is acceptable:

> In April, Google set a deadline for websites to add mobile-friendly coding features that would make the **viewing experience** for mobile users better. ([standardmarketing](http://www.standardmarketing.com/2015/05/the-benefits-of-a-responsive-website-design/))

Answer (score 0):

[**Display**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/display):

The visual representation of the output of an electronic device